# Menu not inflated in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use a `ViewPager` to change between 2 `Fragments`.
For the two Fragments, consider this code:

```
onCreateView{
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
    ...
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.FragmentAnswerToolbar);
    getActivity().setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

}
```

and

```
public final void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        Log.d("onCreateOptionsMenu", "is called");
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_qa, menu);
    }
```

The problem is now, that when i switch from FRAGMENT_A to FRAGMENT_B the menu is not inflated. Notice that they have both the correct `R.id.XYZ`

menu.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="dbis.uni.learnapp.QAActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Summary:
Toolbarmenu is inflated only in FRAGMENT_A and not in FRAGMENT_B

Comment: Have you called supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); after showing the 2nd fragment?

Comment: if you are not inflating toolbar in fragment B then that menu will not come. Try create toolbar in activity and create this 2 fragments inside of it. Will reduce you code maintainability.

Comment: @DrupDesai i inflated it in Fragment B

Comment: @user6547359 no i didnt, what does supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()?

Comment: Grossly, it tells the layoutmanager that it has to reinflate the menu.

Comment: but as per your Summary you said that toolbar is in Fragment A only right..

Comment: @DrupDesai the code you see is in both Fragments